# Как связать выбор нескольких Checkbutton с выполнением основного кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Написал простой генератор паролей. Использую флажки Checkbutton для выбора конкретных символов используемых в генерировании пароля. Выбор нескольких наборов символов для пароля организовал через if.

Подскажите, можно ли упростить код и сделать выбор наборов не через if, ведь Checkbutton может быть не три, а гораздо больше. Буду рад любому совету. Спасибо.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

def generator():
    if Letters.get() == 1:
        list_pas = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ'
    if Numbers.get() == 1:
        list_pas = '0123456789'
    if Symbols.get() == 1:
        list_pas = '<>=-_!@#$%'
    if Letters.get() == 1 and Numbers.get() == 1:
        list_pas = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ0123456789'
    if Letters.get() == 1 and Symbols.get() == 1:
        list_pas = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ<>=-_!@#$%'
    if Numbers.get() == 1 and Symbols.get() == 1:
        list_pas = '0123456789<>=-_!@#$%'
    if Letters.get() == 1 and Numbers.get() == 1 and Symbols.get() == 1:
        list_pas = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ0123456789<>=-_!@#$%'
    try:
        Entry_Long_Pass = Entry_Data.get()
        Entry_Long_Pass = int(Entry_Long_Pass)
        if Entry_Long_Pass < 0:
            messagebox.showwarning('ВНИМАНИЕ', 'ДЛИНА ПАРОЛЯ МЕНЬШЕ 0')
        else:
            pas = ''
            for i in range(Entry_Long_Pass): 
                pas = pas + random.choice(list(list_pas))
            TextWorld.delete(1.0,END)
            TextWorld.insert(END, pas)
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror('ВНИМАНИЕ', 'ПРОВЕРЬ ДЛИНУ ПАРОЛЯ')
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('ВНИМАНИЕ', 'ВЫБЕРИ СИМВОЛЫ ДЛЯ ПАРОЛЯ')
        
root = Tk()
root.title('ГЕНЕРАТОР ПАРОЛЕЙ')
Label(root, text='ДЛИНА ПАРОЛЯ:', font='Arial 11').grid(row=0, column=0)
Entry_Data = Entry(root, width=10, font='Arial 11')
Entry_Data.grid(row=0, column=1)

Letters = IntVar()
Letters_checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(text='A...Z', variable=Letters)
Letters_checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=2)
 
Numbers = IntVar()
Numbers_checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(text='0...9', variable=Numbers)
Numbers_checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=3)
 
Symbols = IntVar()
Symbols_checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(text='!...%', variable=Symbols)
Symbols_checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=4)

Button_pas = Button(root,text='ГЕНЕРАТОР',  font=('Arial', 10), bg='#d8e4bc', fg='black', width=10, height=1, command=generator).grid(row=0,   column=5)

TextWorld = Text(root, font='Arial 11', width=55, height=10, fg='white', bg='black')
TextWorld.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=6)

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо нескольких `if`, вам просто надо вставить "математическое" выражение со строками

```
list_pas = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ' * Letters.get() + '0123456789' * Numbers.get() + '<>=-_!@#$%' * Symbols.get()
```

Тогда в списке будут оставаться только выбранные элементы, так как значения checkbutton равны 0 или 1.

Comment: Интересное решение. Он решает проблему, спасибо. Но может быть ещё есть варианты? Более классические. Ведь например Checkbutton могу использовать для выбора построения конкретных графиков. Там данное решение не подойдёт.

Answer (score 2):

Просто склеивайте нужный набор символов из частей, а не перебирайте все варианты сочетаний чекбоксов, тогда нужно будет всего 3 if-а. Также можно убрать сравнение с 1, т.к. 1 и так эквивалентно истине:

```
    list_pass = ""
    if Letters.get():
        list_pas += 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ'
    if Numbers.get():
        list_pas += '0123456789'
    if Symbols.get():
        list_pas += '<>=-_!@#$%'
```